# How to return the top three values from an array

Tags: ruby

I have a set of data:

```
grade_hash = {bill: [100, 95, 92], frank: [67, 73, 84], sue: [99, 88, 77], karen: [70,80,90], bob: [95, 93, 92]}
```

I also have a grade scale:

```
def letter_grade(score)
  if score >= 90
   "A"
  elsif score >= 80
   "B"
  elsif score >= 70
   "C"
  elsif score >= 60
   "D"
  else
   "F"
  end
end
```

I want to extract those two that have the highest grades.

I have:

```
def top_students(grade_hash, number_of_students)
  grade_hash.transform_values {|nums| letter_grade(nums.reduce(:+)/nums.size)}
end
```

This would give the average of the grades for each student and apply a letter grade. How do I extract the top two?

I tried applying a .sort_by but that didn't work.

Comment: It's not clear how these two bits of code are connected.

Comment: You could alternatively write the method `letter_grade` as follows: `def letter_grade(score); case score; when 0...60 then "F"; when 0...70 then "D"; when 0...80 then "C"; when 0...70 then "B"; else "A"; end; end`. This works because statement use `===`, which here is [Range#===](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D). Also, I've written the ranges with three dots so that (for example) `80` is in the range `80...90` rather than `70...80`. If desired, you could write, for example, `when 70...80 then "C"` instead of `when 0...80 then "C"`.

Comment: You could also write `def letter_grade(score); case score; when 90...101 then "A"; when 80...90 then "B"; when 70...80 then "C"; when 60...70 then "D"; else "F"; end; end`.

Answer (score 0):

To sort you will need to convert to an array.  Hashes are not sortable.

```
grade_hash
  .transform_values {|nums| letter_grade(nums.reduce(:+)/nums.size)}
  .to_a
  .sort_by(&:last)
```

The above will sort the values.

From there you can select the top `n` students and optionally convert back to a hash if you want to keep that format.

```
grade_hash
  .transform_values {|nums| letter_grade(nums.reduce(:+)/nums.size)}
  .to_a               # this is superfluous; .sort_by on a hash will do this internally
  .sort_by(&:last)
  .take(number_of_students)
  .to_h
```

Addendum: CarySwoveland points out that arrays in ruby 2.4 support `sum` so the reduce isn't necessary

```
letter_grade(nums.sum.fdviv(nums.size))
```

Comment: `sort_by` is an `Enumerable` method and `Hash` `include`s `Enumerable`, so why should `to_a` be needed? Try it. Consider `grade_hash.transform_values { |nums| letter_grade(nums.sum.fdiv(nums.size)) }.sort_by(&:last)`. Note I've calculated a floating point average before converting to a letter grade. See [Integer#fdiv](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-fdiv). In #2 try `.min_by(number_of_students, &:last)`. See [Enumerable#min_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

Comment: @CarySwoveland - hashes are not sortable; the order of keys in a hash is undefined.  If you look at the output of your statement, it is an array, not a hash.  It looks like `sort_by` is internally converting to an array, so the `to_a` in my solution is superfluous.

Comment: `sort_by` is an `Enumerable` method ([Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)). All `Enumerable` methods have receivers that are enumerators (instances of the class [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html)). Suppose `h = { a:1, b:2 }`. When Ruby sees `h.sort_by {...}`, recognizing `sort_by` is an `Enumerable` method, she sends `h` the method [Hash#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-each) (without a block) to convert it to the enumerator `enum = h.each #=> #<Enumerator: {:a=>1, :b=>2}:each>`. (cont..)

Comment: We're having a slight miscommunication due to semantics.  I agree that you get a sorted *result* when you call `sort_by`.  My argument is that a `Hash` *data structure* cannot be sorted.  A hash is an unordered set of key/value pairs; sorting has no meaning because the *data structure* has no order.  When you call `each` the hash is *serialized* and sorting becomes possible but the result of the sort is no longer a hash, it is an array.  Observe: `grade_hash.sort_by(&:last).class` returns `Array`.  The same logic applies to a `Set`; you can call `sort` but the result is no longer a `Set`

Comment: ..So Ruby actually executes `h.each.sort_by {...}` or `enum.sort_by {...}`. `enum` generates elements that are passed to `sort_by`: `enum.next #=>   [:a, 1]; enum.next #=> [:b, 2]; enum.next #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end`. `sort_by` does not know that these are key-value pairs from a hash. They could as well be elements of an array or some other class `C` that `include`s `Enumerable` (and therefore implements `C#each`). That is why `sort_by` was designed to return an array of pairs.

Comment: You are saying  one can't sort a hash to produce a hash whose key-value pairs are ordered (though that's irrelevant to whether you need `to_a`). Actually, that's not quite accurate. Since v1.9 Ruby guarantees that key-insertion order is maintained. Therefore, `h.sort.to_h` produces a hash whose key-value pairs are ordered by [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E). Ordering key-value pairs in that way was controversial, but many of us have found useful applications of that property. I'll agree with you that sets cannot be ordered to produce ordered sets. :-)